# Setting object property with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-operator

I am trying to set an object property using a ternary operator but I can't see to be able to do it. I am getting this error: > ',' expected.

Here's the code am using:

```
for(let i =0; i < res.value.length; i++ ){
          let event = res.value[i]
          events.push({ 
            eventEndDate: event.EndTime && '', 
            eventName: event.Title, 
            eventStartDate: event.StartTime && '', 
            numOfAttendees: event.RSVPId?? event.RSVPId.length :  0, //here's my issue
            eventId: event.Id
          })
        }
```

I want to set the numOfAttendees to 0 if event.RSVPId is null, otherwise I want to set it to the length of that property. What am I doing wrong here? Isn't this how it's supposed to be written?

Comment: cause your are using `event.RSVPId??` two `?` marks, try with one `?`

Comment: a stupid mistake. Thanks

Comment: no worries !! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(let i =0; i < res.value.length; i++ ){
          let event = res.value[i]
          events.push({ 
            eventEndDate: event.EndTime && '', 
            eventName: event.Title, 
            eventStartDate: event.StartTime && '', 
            numOfAttendees: event.RSVPId? event.RSVPId.length :  0, //here's my issue
            eventId: event.Id
          })
        }
```

You had two `?` instead of 1

> `event.RSVPId?? event.RSVPId.length :  0`

is suppose to be

> `event.RSVPId? event.RSVPId.length :  0`

Comment: If ternary is not working and the syntax is correct, you need to check for the condition. Because of the flexibility of JS we tend to give an array thinking whether it is like a primitive type variable. But you have to check for the array.length > 0